# Save command to history without executing in bash

Tags: bash, history

Is there a way to save a command in bash history without executing it?
e.g.

```
$ cmd [a long list of arguments]
```

and now during typing i remember I'd like to do something else first. 
Can I have something like

```
$ cmd [a long list of arguments][some-key-strokes]
```

and this does not actually execute but goes into bash history so that I can use it later?

Comment: In that situation, I just prefix the line with `#`, and then hit Enter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you can use history expansion's `:p` modifier to print the current comment line without executing.  `!#` is the current line, and `%` by itself will match nothing

```
$ cmd [arguments] !#%:p
```

Comment: cool! ;) and without need of escaping special chars in the command what can get messy if the command is not just `ls -al` +1

Comment: cool! very neat

Comment: `Ctrl-U`, do that other stuff, then `Ctrl-Y` is the better way you speak of.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-s` option to the `history` command:

```
history -s cmd arg1 arg2
```

The call to `history -s` itself, conveniently, is not added to the command history, so in your history it appears as if you executed `cmd` without actually doing so.

Comment: cool! this is also awesome

Answer (score 4):

I think the "some key strokes" you want are Ctrl-U and Ctr-Y which store a line in to the kill-ring, and then yank it back out later. It doesn't go into the history, but then I think it shouldn't, as you didn't do it.

[Readline Killing Commands](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html#SEC46)

[Killing And Yanking](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html#SEC55)

I learned this years ago, then forgot and went looking for those key strokes too.

It's discussed here too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/how-to-save-a-command-you-entered-without-executing-it

Comment: Most underrated comment on this subject that I have found! Thanks for this, it works like a charm :-)

Comment: This is the right GNU way of doing so, should be considered the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I just add a # to the begin of the line to transform the line into a comment:

```
#cmd [a long list of arguments]
```

I prefer this way because you can do it with just 3 [4 if you need SHIFT to insert #] keystrokes

```
^a#<ENTER>
```

^a goes to the begin of current line

# adds the comment

ENTER executes the comment

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is done by

```
echo 'cmd [a long list of arguments]' >> /home/you/bash_history
```

Note that the name of the history can differ on your system. Therefore you can use the `HISTFILE` environment var

what makes:

```
echo 'cmd [a long list of arguments]' >> "$HISTFILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

> In that situation, I just prefix the line with #, and then hit Enter.

... or use the key combo: `ESC #`

```
bind -p | grep -i 'insert-comment'   # "\e#": insert-comment
```

See also: [Bash - save command without executing it](http://unstableme.blogspot.de/2009/08/bash-save-command-without-executing-it.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a space and | (pipe) at the end of the line, hitting enter, and then Ctrl-C'ing.

(<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

The command will be in your history with a | at the end (can simply remove with backspace) instead of a # at the beginning (potentially more tedious to remove).

DISCLAIMER: I don't know if this always works! Use at your own risk!

> $ cmd [long arguments list] |
>
> >
>   <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
>
> $ <kbd>Up</kbd>
>
> $ cmd [long arguments list] |

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this line:

`history -s -p $COMMAND`

From `help`:

```
The -p option means to perform
history expansion on each ARG and display the result,
```

This means you can expand things like `!!` and store the result at the bottom of history.

Comment: `history -s` was given in an answer two years ago.  Does the `-p` improve on that?  What does `-p` do?  (To the extent that it makes sense to do so, you should [edit] your answer to make it better, and not respond to my comment with another comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go to the beginning of the line and do the thing you were going to do followed by &&, like

```
rm old_file && cmd [args]
```

So if the thing you wanted to do succeeds, your command will run immediately afterwards, and if it fails you command won't run, but it'll be in history. You could also do

```
test && cmd [args]
```

Since test with no args will fail, but this is a handful of extra keystrokes compared to the `#` method.